# Tableau calculation: I am trying to calculate the percentage of running sum but am unable to create a calculation

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate number of customers which represent 80% of the profit so that I can use it in a calculated field which I can use in a reference line.

This is what I wrote

```
     IIF(RUNNING_SUM([Profit])= (0.8*SUM([Profit])),
     COUNTD([Customer Name]),0)
```

but it gives me error saying

```
 "All fields must be constant or aggregate when using table calculation functions"
```

The logic is to "Count distinct number of customers which represent 80% of running total profits"

This is meant for a pareto chart, so the values are already sorted in descending order for it to work.

How do I create such calculated field which would give me number of top customers which will represent 80% of the profits?

Let me know if more clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a Pareto Chart. This might help:

http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2014/08/27/pareto-charts-tableau/

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage the power of Table Calculations, where you can first do running total of profit and then simply calculate percentage of total.

Here is the link to step-by-step tutorial in Tableau10 for Pareto Analysis (80/20 rule):
https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/pareto-charts?signin=15df68b66e703787258911e79db040a7.

Hope this helps.